# Visual Studio – New .Net form designer – File is corrupt. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013110E)

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework, exceptions

When I open or create a .Net form, I get this exception in the designer.

File is corrupt. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013110E)

It was working fine but a couple of days ago. 
I re-installed Visual Studio, but I still get the same exception. 
Is there an option that I didn't select?

Here the stack trace:

> **Instances of this error (1)**

```
 1.   Hide Call Stack at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkDispenser.OpenScope(String fileName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.OpenMetadataFile(String fileName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.LoadModule(String path)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetTypeFromTargetLocation(Type type, Boolean validateBase)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUniverse.GetType(Type type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkUtil.GetCustomAttributes(Type type, Type filter, Boolean inherit, CustomAttributesCache cache)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkType.GetCustomAttributes(Type filter, Boolean inherit)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(Type type, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.GetAttributes(MemberInfo member, Type filter)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.VsTargetFrameworkAttributeCollection.get_Attributes()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.EnsureExtensions(IComponent component)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateInstance(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Comment: Third/Fourth time a charm... I haven't find the actual issue but I kept re-installing and it finally worked. I'm sorry for all those looking for an anwser... Wish you all luck!